# Bash: test mutual equality of multiple variables?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

What is the right way to test if several variables are all equal?

```
if [[ $var1 = $var2 = $var3 ]] # syntax error
```

Is it necessary to write something like the following?

```
if [[ $var1 = $var2 && $var1 = $var3 && $var2 = $var3 ]] # cumbersome
if [[ $var1 = $var2 && $var2 = $var3 && $var3 = $var4 ]] # somewhat better
```

Unfortunately, the otherwise excellent [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and other online sources I could find don't provide such an example.

My particular motivation is to test if several directories all have the same number of files, using `ls -1 $dir | wc -l` to count files.

**Note**

"var1" etc. are example variables.  I'm looking for a solution for arbitrary variable names, not just those with a predictable numeric ending.

**Update**

I've accepted Richo's answer, as it is the most general.  However, I'm actually using Kyle's because it's the simplest and my inputs are guaranteed to avoid the caveat.

Thanks for the suggestions, everyone.

Comment: You only need N-1 tests for N variables.  If var1 and var2 are equal, and var2 and var3 are equal, then you don't have to test whether var1 and var3 are equal.  Do you have a fixed number of variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to test equality of an arbitrary number of items (let's call them $item1-5, but they could be an array

```
st=0
for i in $item2 $item3 $item4 $item5; do
    [ "$item1" = "$i" ]
    st=$(( $? + st ))
done

if [ $st -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "They were all the same"
fi
```

Comment: You can even `break` if the comparison fails if you only want to report "They were all the same" or not.

Comment: What is the outermost `$` for, and why do we need double parentheses? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Double parentheses to do arithmetic, the `$` is to return the value so that we can assign it to ``st``

Answer (score 2):

If they are single words you can get really cheap about it.

```
varUniqCount=`echo "${var1} ${var2} ${var3} ${var4}" | sort -u | wc -l`
if [ ${varUniqCount} -gt 1 ]; then
   echo "Do not match"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

(edited to include delimiters to fix the problem noted by Keith Thompson)

Treating the variable values as strings, you can concatenate them along with a suitable delimiter and do one comparison:

```
if [[ "$var1|$var2|$var3" = "$var1|$var1|$var1" ]]
```

I used = instead == because == isn't an equality comparison inside [[ ]], it is a pattern match.

Comment: What if they were numbers? The standard file counting trick returns strings, but in principle they could be numbers instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  As long any given number is always output the same way, i.e. 3 is always "3" or "03" or "003", but not "3" sometimes and "003" other times, then the comparison should work.

Comment: Clever, but it fails for `var2=abc`, `var2=ab`, `var3=`cabc`.  You can fix that by adding a delimiter between the strings that never appears n any of them (which may not always be possible), such as `"$var1|$var2|$var3" = "$var1|$var1|$var1`.

Comment: Ha, nice catch.  Delimiters should work OK for the simple case involving just numbers.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer; my edit didn't fix that problem.

Comment: I fear the statement about `=` vs. `==` is misleading: `=` and `==` inside `[[ ... ]]` act the _same_ (`=` is just an alias for POSIX compliance): if the right operand is _single- or double-quoted_, then the operation IS an _equality_ comparison; otherwise, it is a pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

**Transitive method** of inspection.

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=10
var2=10
var3=10

if [[ ($var1 == $var2) && ($var2 == $var3) ]]; then 
    echo "yay"
else
    echo "nay"
fi
```

#### Output:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] ./s.sh 
yay
```

---

#### Note:

Since you have stated in your question that your objective is to test several directories that have same number of files, I thought of the following solution. I know this isn't something you had request so please feel free to disregard it.

#### Step1:

Identify number of files in a given directory. This command will look inside sub-dirs too but that can be controlled using `-depth` option of `find`.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -type d -exec sh -c "printf {} && ls -1 {} | wc -l " \;
.       9
./Backup       7
./bash       2
./GTP      22
./GTP/ParserDump      11
./GTP/ParserDump/ParserDump       1
./perl       7
./perl/p1       2
./python       1
./ruby       0
./scripts      22
```

#### Step2:

This can be combined with `Step1` as we are just redirecting the content to a file.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] find . -type d -exec sh -c "printf {} && ls -1 {} | wc -l " \; > file.temp
```

#### Step3:

Using the following command we will look in the file.temp twice and it will give us a list of directories that have same number of files.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==FNR && a[$2]++ {b[$2];next} ($2 in b)' file.temp file.temp | sort -k2
./GTP/ParserDump/ParserDump       1
./python       1
./bash       2
./perl/p1       2
./Backup       7
./perl       7
./GTP      22
./scripts      22
```

Comment: Thanks, but my actual variables are not named so conveniently / obscurely. I've updated the question to reflect I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: The solution doesn't depend on the names of the variables; in particular, it makes no use of the fact that their names end in numbers.

Comment: Hi @reve_etrange, I have added a solution to your main objective, since it is not something you had requested, please feel free to disregard it.

Comment: @KeithThompson That comment was with respect to a previous iteration of the answer that placed the variables into an array using a range on their end character, and then looped over that array to perform the test.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, this should work:

```
distinct_values=$(for dir in this_dir that_dir another_dir ; do ls -l "$dir" | wc -l ; done | uniq | wc -l)
if [ $distinct_values -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo All the same
else
    echo Not all the same
fi
```

Explanation:

- `ls -l "$dir"` lists the files and subdirectories in the directory, one per line (omitting dot files).
- Piping the output through `wc -l` gives you the number of files in the directory.
- Doing that consecutively for each directory in the list gives you a list consisting of the number of files in each directory; if there are 7 in each, this gives 3 lines each consisting of the number `7`
- Piping that through `uniq` eliminates consecutive duplicate lines.
- Piping *that* through `wc -l` gives you the number of distinct lines, which will be 1 if and only if all the directories contain the same number of files.

Note that the output of the 4th stage doesn't necessarily give you the number of distinct numbers of files in the directories; `uniq` only removes *adjacent* duplicates, so if the inputs are `7 6 7`, the two `7`s won't be merged.  But it will merge all lines into 1 *only* if they're all the same.

This is the power of the Unix command line: putting small tools together to do interesting and useful things.  (Show me a GUI that can do that!)

For values stored in variables, replace the first line by:

```
distinct_values=$(echo "$this_var" "$that_var" "$another_var" | fmt -1 | uniq | wc -l)
```

This assumes that the values of the variables don't contain spaces.

Comment: Can you explain how the comparison works? Is it really supposed to be to `1` (as `0` is `true` in bash)?

Comment: @reve_etrange: I've updated the answer with an explanation; the `1` is just a number, not a true/false or success/failure status.  (BTW, I'm not sure I'd day that `0` is `true` in bash; it's more accurate to say that it denotes *success*.)

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, and this answer is probably the *coolest*. If I could, I'd mark more than one of these correct...I think Richo's is the most general, and Kyle's is the simplest...