# compare three or more variables are not equal in bash

Tags: bash, equality

I can't figure how to detect equality and return equal vars, tried many way with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812089/bash-test-mutual-equality-of-multiple-variables)

```
    tag="AA"
prst_tag[1]="BB"
prst_tag[2]="CC"
prst_tag[3]="AA"
prst_tag[4]="EE"
```

What i exactly want to do:

```
if $tag or ${prst_tag[1]} or ${prst_tag[2]} or ${prst_tag[3]} or ${prst_tag[4]} have equal value; then
    echo "equal TAG found"
    echo "tag: $tag"
    echo "prst_tag[1]: ${prst_tag[1]}"
    echo "prst_tag[2]: ${prst_tag[2]}"
    echo "prst_tag[3]: ${prst_tag[3]}"
    echo "prst_tag[4]: ${prst_tag[4]}"
fi
```

Help appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to make shure there is no same vars, like AA.

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: been searching for an hour and a half, tested all answers and comment in the thread linked above.

Comment: You want to make sure the elements of array `prst_tag` have no duplicates (are unique)? How does variable `tag` come into play?

Comment: Please post the trial code which does not work, explain what it results in (and why that isn't what you want).  Your question still lacks a clear explanation what you expect these two (or five, depending on how you count) variables should result in.

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand your question, but i assume you want to compare strings. Here is example how to compare string with array of strings:

```
tag="AA"
prst_tag[1]="BB"
prst_tag[2]="CC"
prst_tag[3]="AA"
prst_tag[4]="EE"
found=false

for i in "${prst_tag[@]}"
do
   if [ "$tag" = "$i" ]; then
     found=true
   fi 
done

if [ "$found" = "true" ];then
   echo "equal TAG found"
else 
   echo "equal TAG not found"
fi
```

Comment: sorry not easy with my english knowledge, i have edited my question. i have already tested a similar code from the linked thread, but that's not exactly what i want to do.

Comment: I edited my answer check it, maybe this is what you want

Comment: thanks for your effort but that's not what i want. i want to detect if `$tag ${prst_tag[1]} ${prst_tag[2]} ${prst_tag[3]} ${prst_tag[4]}` have same value.