# unix shell script for checking three variables are same

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i want to check if all three variables are same then print msg

```
if [ "$x1" == "$x2" == "$3" ];
 then 
 echo "all are same"
fi
```

I am getting this error:

> [: too many arguments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: test mutual equality of multiple variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812089/bash-test-mutual-equality-of-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot compare three variables at the time. Instead, do compare them in blocks of two:

```
if [ "$x1" = "$x2" ] && [ "$x2" = "$x3" ];
then
   echo "all are same"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `bash`, I'd recommend using

```
if [[ "$x1" == "$x2"  && "$x2" == "$x3" ]]; then
```

If you need/want to maintain POSIX compatibility using `[ ... ]`, then you should not use `==`.

```
if [ "$x1" = "$x2" ] && [ "$x2" = "$x3" ]; then
```

`bash` lets you use the non-standard `==` with `[`, but there's little point in mixing standard and non-standard behavior.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
if [ "$x1" = "$x2" -a "$x2" = "$x3" ]
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/jnlctq)

Comment: The POSIX standard itself recommends using `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead of `[ ... -a ... ]`.

Comment: `&&` *outside* the command is standard POSIX. If you are using `[[`, you can include the `&&` *inside* the `[[`.